# Python OpenCV - Erro ao usar função de desenho

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, drawing

Eu já consegui executar esse código antes, porém agora não funciona. Ele precisa desenhar um quadrado na tela do vídeo.

Erro:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>      File "/home/ggoulart/PycharmProjects/INTPYT_HandTracker/Main.py", line    13, in 
>      cv2.rectangle(gray, 100, 100, (0,255,0), 3)
>      SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple

E o código executado:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Loop
while (1):

    _, frame = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.rectangle(gray, 100, 100, (0,255,0), 3)

    cv2.imshow('Test',gray)

    k = cv2.waitKey(100)
    if k == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Informações adicionais:**

OpenCV version: 3.x

Host OS: Linux (Fedora 23)

Compiler & CMake: GCC 5.3 & CMake 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A chamada da função `cv2.rectangle()` está incorreta.

O segundo e o terceiro parametro são tuplas que representam as coordenadas dos vértices opostos do retângulo que será desenhado na imagem.

A chamada abaixo desenha um retângulo de `100x100` pixels na coordenada `0,0` na imagem:

```
cv2.rectangle(gray, (0,0), (100,100), (0,255,0), 3)
```

Referência:

> **cv.Rectangle( img, pt1, pt2, color, thickness=1, lineType=8, shift=0 ) → None**
>
> **img** – Image.
>
> **pt1** – Vertex of the rectangle.
>
> **pt2** – Vertex of the rectangle opposite to pt1
>
> **rec** – Alternative specification of the drawn rectangle.
>
> **color** – Rectangle color or brightness (grayscale image).
>
> **thickness** – Thickness of lines that make up the rectangle. Negative values, like CV_FILLED , mean that the function has to draw a
>   filled rectangle.
>
> **lineType** – Type of the line. See the line() description.
>
> **shift** – Number of fractional bits in the point coordinates.

Espero ter ajudado.